# How to populate a 2-D array with member variables of a custom object and a specific format

Tags: java, arrays, excel, arraylist, output

I have been tasked with taking a massive list of IPs and comparing said list to all the the IPs in the many workgroups on our network. I have to format my data into an excel spreadsheet and, using Apache POI, I am struggling to properly fill the spreadsheet with the necessary data. This data is stored in member variables within custom objects.

Example of successful output in *.txt format:

```
IP Address:               10.224.0.183
ATSG Hits:                2
CIS Hits:                 0
DPS Hits:                 0
Gabelli Admin Hits:       2
Gabelli Labs Hits:        0
ITAC Hits:                0
Law Servers Hits:         0
Law Workstations Hits:    0
Library Servers Hits:     0
Library Workstation Hits: 0
Netenrich Hits:           0
PCI Hits:                 0
UV Environment Hits:      0
```

Example of what I WANT in *.xlxs format:

```
     IP         ATSG     CIS   DPS   Admin  Total
100.100.100.100   0       0     3      1      4
```

Each counter is stored as a member variable in the ipObject class. This class stores a given IP address as well as the number of times it appears in the above workgroup lists. Can i use a loop to automatically populate a 2-D array to be used in Excel with Apache POI?

ipObject Class:

```
public class ipObject 
{
    ipObject()
    {
        IP = null;

        atsgHits = 0;
        cisHits = 0;
        dpsHits = 0;
        adminHits = 0;
        labsHits = 0;
        itacHits = 0;
        lawserversHits = 0;
        lawworkHits = 0;
        libservHits = 0;
        libworkHits = 0;
        netenrichHits = 0;
        pciHits = 0;
        ucenvHits = 0;

        totalHits = 0;
    }

    ipObject(String ipAdd)
    {
        IP = ipAdd;

        atsgHits = 0;
        cisHits = 0;
        dpsHits = 0;
        adminHits = 0;
        labsHits = 0;
        itacHits = 0;
        lawserversHits = 0;
        lawworkHits = 0;
        libservHits = 0;
        libworkHits = 0;
        netenrichHits = 0;
        pciHits = 0;
        ucenvHits = 0;

        totalHits = 0;
    }

    public String IP;

    int atsgHits;
    int cisHits;
    int dpsHits;
    int adminHits;
    int labsHits;
    int itacHits;
    int lawserversHits;
    int lawworkHits;
    int libservHits;
    int libworkHits;
    int netenrichHits;
    int pciHits;
    int ucenvHits;

    int totalHits = (atsgHits + cisHits + dpsHits + adminHits + labsHits + itacHits + lawserversHits + lawworkHits 
            + libservHits + libworkHits + netenrichHits + pciHits + ucenvHits);
}
```

excelExport() Class:

```
public static void excelExport() 
    {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
        Object[][] datatypes = 
            {
                {"IP", "ATSG", "CIS", "DPS", "Admin", "Labs", "ITAC", "Law Servers", "Law Workstations", "Library Servers", "library Workstations", "Netenrich", "PCI", "UC Environment", "Total"},
                {"int", "Primitive", 2},
                {"float", "Primitive", 4},
                {"double", "Primitive", 8},
                {"char", "Primitive", 1},
                {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size"}
        };

        int rowNum = 0;
        System.out.println("Creating excel");

        for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) 
        {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) 
            {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                if (field instanceof String) 
                {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) 
                {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```